# HQL: select from JSON

Tags: java, json, hql

I have this class:

```
class School {
 private Map<String, Object> questionnaire;

}
...
```

`Questionnaire` is stored in my db as a `VARCHAR(MAX)` json
and I would like to query it like this:

```
select sch from School where sch.questionnaire['5'] like '%02.%'
```

Which of course does not work. How to query through `Map` in HQL ? If possible with out using `JSON_QUERY`.

Comment: http://www.javachain.com/how-to-parse-json-using-apache-hive-query-language/